# using UserControl as item template for ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf

OK, I think similar questions have already been asked, but I can't get this to work. I have a View with an ItemsControl like this:

```
<Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Model Health Report:" Margin="10,10,10,0" Height="26" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold"/>
        <ItemsControl Grid.Row="1" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding HealthReports, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type hr:HealthReportSummaryControl}"/>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
```

That has a view model behind it like this:

```
public class CommunicatorViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<HealthReportSummaryViewModel> HealthReports { get; set; }
    public CommunicatorModel Model { get; set; }

    public CommunicatorViewModel(HealthReportData data)
    {
        Model = new CommunicatorModel();
        HealthReports = new ObservableCollection<HealthReportSummaryViewModel>
    {
        new HealthReportSummaryViewModel {Title = "View1", Description = "Some desc."},
        new HealthReportSummaryViewModel {Title = "View2", Description = "Some desc."}
    };
}
```

}

As you can see I am binding it to an ObservableCollection of HealthReportSummaryViewModel objects. These are populated in the constructor. I checked the objects at runtime, they are correct.

The actual control looks like this:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Ellipse Grid.Column="0" 
                 Fill="{Binding FillColor}"  
                 Margin="2"/>
        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" 
                   Fill="DarkGray"
                   Margin="0,2"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Title}" 
               Grid.Column="2" 
               Margin="5,0,10,0" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" 
                   Margin="5,10,10,0" 
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                   Text="{Binding Description}"/>
    </Grid>
```

With a view model:

```
public class HealthReportSummaryViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private System.Windows.Media.Color _fillColor;
        public System.Windows.Media.Color FillColor {
            get { return _fillColor; }
            set { _fillColor = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => FillColor); }
        }

        private string _title;
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { _title = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Title); }
        }

        private string _description;
        public string Description
        {
            get { return _description; }
            set { _description = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Description); }
        }
    }
```

I am getting no exceptions, but my window has only empty items. There is a rectangle in the user control that is not dependent on data binding so perhaps this is an issue with the size of the content? I can't figure this out. It's all blank. Do I need to somehow set the size for each ItemsControl item, or will they just adjust to size of the grid they are placed in? What am i missing here? All help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your `DataTemplate` is empty, so you see the empty items.

Comment: How so? doesn't it supposed to create a new instance of HealthReportSummaryControl for every HealthReportSummaryViewModel in the HealthReports?

Comment: So I guess I want to use my HealthReportSummaryControl which is a UserControl as my data template. How can i add that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `DataTemplate` definition is wrong:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type hr:HealthReportSummaryControl}"/>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

This defines an empty data template for the items of the `HealthReportSummaryControl` type.

Instead, you should define it like that:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type hr:HealthReportSummaryViewModel}">
        <hr:HealthReportSummaryControl/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

This defines a template for the `HealthReportSummaryViewModel` items.